# E11000 duplicate key error collection in spring data mongo when using custom String as a primary key

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

> I want to use a custom String *code* as a **primary key** in my collection and ensure that **Mongo Repository *save* updates/upserts** the document based on code. But when a 2nd entry is added with same code, it throws **E11000 duplicate key error collection**. PFB my code snippet :

```
public class WebCategoryTemp {

@Id
private String code;
@Indexed
private Long timestamp;
private String name;
private String parent;
private Map<String,String> attributes;
private List<String> brands;
private List<String> categories;
private List<String> optionCodes;

}
```

> Repository:

```
public interface WebCategoryTempRepository extends 
MongoRepository<WebCategoryTemp, String> {
}
```

> I am getting the below exception while adding another entry with same code :

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: E11000 duplicate key error 
  collection: AQUAMAN.webCategoryTemp index: _id_ dup key: { _id: 
  "GlobalTrends" }; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: 
  E11000 duplicate key error collection: AQUAMAN.webCategoryTemp index: _id_ 
  dup key: { _id: "GlobalTrends" }
```

> Sample Mongo Document:

```
{
    "_id" : "GlobalTrends",
    "timestamp" : NumberLong("1570439407216"),
    "name" : "GlobalTrendss",
    "parent" : "83",
    "attributes" : {
        "categoryLevel" : "4",
        "returnWindow" : "35",
        "isReturnable" : "true",
        "maximumQuantity" : "2",
        "categoryToggle" : "toggleCode",
        "catalogId" : "rilfnlProductCatalog"
    },
    "brands" : [ ],
    "categories" : [
        "830316001"
    ],
    "version" : NumberLong(0)
}
```

> Solution:
> This issue occurs when you try to **save** an already existing db object with spring data.
> As a fix for this issue, we should hit a find query first to mongo to check if the object exists. If find returns the mongo object, we should update the same reference and then save it.

Comment: `_id`s must be unique and are immutable. If you want to update, you have to call the update method.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Save inherited from org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository by definition, is supposed to update an object in the upsert style, update if present and insert if not. When calling save , I am passing the code field in the POJO, so ideally it should check if code is same, it should update the document.

Comment: @Priancy Have you found the solution, facing the same issue.

Comment: @priancy I am also facing the same, did you get some solution for this?

Comment: @AayushMall This issue occurs when you try to insert a new java object with the same id in mongo.  If you wish to update an existing object in mongo, you have to get that object first from database and update the fields and save the same object again.